# Looking for a zip code lookup database to get city and state

Tags: javascript, forms, geo-location

I would like to improve my forms and remove city and state fields so that there are 2 less fields to fill out. I have an input field for city and select drop-down for state. Instead of asking visitors to fill them out, I can do a look up via JavaScript or backend like php to populate the city and state before saving the record in my database. I'm leaning towards a web service versus an offline zip db that I would have to keep up to date.

Are there any free or cheap tools I can use to populate city and state based on zip code provided?

Comment: Maybe you can find a database on [opendata](opendata.stackexchange.com) depending on the regions you need e.g. [Is there a tool to match zip codes to cities?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/929/7097)  [Trying to link ZIP code to core-based statistical area](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10447/7097)
[Any help on getting the city or zip codes that make up metropolitan statistical areas?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11950/7097)

Comment: What kind of fields you're talking about? What your website is using (Wordpress/Drupal/Wix)? Is it for back-end or front-end? Are you looking for JavaScript or PHP/Python library, a web service (like Google Places API) or just the plain off-line database?

Comment: I have an input field for city and select drop-down for state..Instead of asking visitors to fill them out, I can do a look up via JavaScript or backend like php to populate the city and state before saving the record in my database. I'm leaning towards a web service versus an offline zip db that I would have to keep up to date.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Details from your comment e.g. should be part of the question body.

Comment: Can you define "cheap"? See, for instance, my comment to @Jane's asnwer

Answer (score 2):

You can look into zip apis that allow you to receive city and state based on provided zip code. One that is free to use is [zipapi.us](http://zipapi.us) and they provide what you are needing to accomplish with your form.

Comment: Free for 10 requests per hour, 240 per day; thereafter, the pricing plan is [here](http://zipapi.us/plans/)